# Improving spam classification with tensorflow logistic regression

Tags: logistic, classification, accuracy, loss-functions, tensorflow

I would like to classify a mail (spam = 1/ham = 0), using logistic regression. My implementation is similar to [this implementation](http://jrmeyer.github.io/machinelearning/2016/02/01/TensorFlow-Tutorial.html) and using tensorflow.

A mail is represented as a bag-of-words vector, with each number in the vector representing how often a term appeared in a mail. The idea is to multiply that with a vector, and use the sign-function to turn regression into classification. $$y_{predicted} = \sigma(x_i^T\theta) $$, with $\sigma = \frac{1}{1 +  e^{-x}}$. To calculate the loss, I am using the l2-loss (squared loss). Since I have a lot of trainig data, regularization seems not necessary (training and testing accuracy is always very close). Still I only get a max accuracy of about 90% (both training and testing). How can I improve this?

I already tried the following:

- Use regularization, L1, L2 with different strength (seems not necessary)
- Use different learning rates
- Use gradient descent, stochastic gradient descent and batch gradient descent (the hope is to avoid local minima in the loss-function, by introducing more variance with stochastic/batch gradient descent)
- create more training data (classes were disbalanced 80/20 spam/ham), using [SMOTE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97555/handling-unbalanced-data-using-smote-no-big-difference)

Things that I could still try:

- use a different loss function

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L2 loss for logistic regression is not convex, but the cross entropy loss is. I’d recommend making the switch because convexity is a really nice property to have during optimization. Convexity implies that you don’t have to worry about local minima because they don’t exist by definition.

A nice discussion of the mathematics comparing the convexity of log loss to the non-convexity of L2 loss can be found here: [What is happening here, when I use squared loss in logistic regression setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326350/what-is-happening-here-when-i-use-squared-loss-in-logistic-regression-setting)

The textbook way to estimate logistic regression coefficients is called Newton-Raphson updating, but I don't believe that it is implemented in TensorFlow since second-order methods are not generally used for neural networks. However, you might improve the rate of convergence if you use SGD + classical momentum or SGD + Nesterov momentum. Nesterov momentum is especially appealing in this case: since your problem is convex, the problem is more-or-less locally quadratic, and that is the use case where Nesterov momentum really shines.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will have a look into it and then repo how good a result it gave me

Comment: Thank you again! I am not at more than 98% accuracy for training and testing, with training still going

Comment: That sounds like a pretty nice improvement, though. Almost 10%! -- in your post, you said you were getting 90% accuracy.

Comment: Yes, it is very impressive indeed! And it seems as though I still do not need any regularization, since training and testing accuracy are fairly close together