# After applying SMOTE, the class distribution doesn't match the real world. Is this a problem?

Tags: classification, python, unbalanced-classes, smote

I have an extremely unbalanced dataset with two classes:

```
1: 1,800 # class 1 
0: 40,000 # class 0
```

This is real world customer data of churned/not churned

If I were to use `smote` to oversample / undersample, the model would be trained on an artificially created distribution of classes that does not reflect the real world whatsoever.

Should the training data reflect the real world, or is `smote` a widely used technique to balance the classes in production environments? I feel like I would be training a model for a completely different task if the training data doesn't reflect the unseen data.

My model is currently performing quite poorly on the `1` class, which is why I'm investigating `smote`.

Any insight is appreciated from people who have used smote. I can't find info of this issue in smote tutorials online. So perhaps it's not an issue?

Comment: It is bad statistical practice that requires excluding data in order to make the method work.  This is a symptom of using the [wrong accuracy scoring rule](http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage), and often of [misrecognizing the problem as classification instead of prediction](http://fharrell.com/post/classification).

Comment: I am monitoring precison, recall, fscore and area under the precision-recall curve. I am also predicting probabilities and converting them to labels using different thresholds. The results are still not great even with threshold adjustment, which is why I am now investigating smote. I read your link, are you suggesting I evaluate the model with the suggested metrics such as "Brier score" rather than what I've already mentioned? In any case I am am looking for info on smote. You mention it's bad statistical practice - so it shouldn't be used at all I guess?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I can't find anything about smote in that link.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97555/handling-unbalanced-data-using-smote-no-big-difference  and search this site!  The link is mostly an explanation of the comments here by @Frank Harrell Take those seriously!